# Help installing the network scanner from a Brother MFC-J6910DW?

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, scanner

The printer driver install and setup is completed and working fine.

(Installed via Brothers install scripts)

The machine is connected to the network on 192.168.1.4 and if I point a web browser to the address I get the admin interface, which is a good sign but otherwise doesnt help much (no linux support provided).

If I launch Xsane scanner I get the error message

> Failed to open device `brother4:net1;dev0':Invalid argument

My question where do I go from here, i.e. what are the typical steps one should take when debugging a network scanner install?
Should I:

1. Check drivers are installed?
2. Ensure ubuntu is aware that there is a scanner on the network  ?

I just dont know the commands or location to check these items

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking the drivers.  My printer has a separate printer and scanner driver for Linux, and I had to install both. For windows it's usually all a single software package.  With Linux it might look like a single software package but be careful, especially if it came as a tarball.

Dora

Comment: Thanks Dora, can you tell me how to check the drivers?